# select rownum from salary where rownum=3;

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How to retrieve third row from any table using "rownum" key word ( i am using oracle-10g)

Comment: @Jagan, what is your RDBMS? And please provide result of 'Select s.*, rownum from salary s'.

Comment: How are we meant to guess what your problem is without knowing your schema or (at the very least) some sample data over which the problem occurs? -1

Comment: if the query (i.e your title) is correct, then the answer is a single row containing 3 !!

Comment: More tags would be nice. I assume you are using Oracle.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - your comment is logical and reasonable, but isn't what you'll find in Oracle. Oracle assigns ROWNUM values as rows are 'spit out' by the query (in effect, after the WHERE clause has been evaluated) - thus, there will not be a row with ROWNUM=3 until rows with ROWNUM=1 and ROWNUM=2 are produced. It's kind of a tail-chasing sort of thing - the query is looking for ROWNUM=3, but the only row which could be produced (since it's obviously looking for a single row) would have ROWNUM=1 - and thus, no results are produced at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oracle assigns values to ROWNUM sequentially as rows are produced by the query - thus, the first row fetched gets ROWNUM=1, the second row fetched gets ROWNUM=2, the third row fetched gets ROWNUM=3, etc.  Notice - for a row to be assigned ROWNUM=3 two preceding rows MUST be fetched.  And this is why your query returns no rows.  You're asking the database for the third row fetched - but rows 1 and 2 have never been fetched.

To demonstrate, try running the following queries:

```
SELECT S.* FROM SALARY S;          -- Should return all rows
SELECT ROWNUM, S.* FROM SALARY S;  -- Should return all rows with ROWNUM prepended
SELECT ROWNUM, S.* FROM SALARY WHERE ROWNUM=3;  -- Should return no rows
```

To work around your problem, try the following:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER FROM
  (SELECT ROWNUM AS ROW_NUMBER, S.* FROM SALARY S)
  WHERE ROW_NUMBER = 3;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

You would [need to do](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html) something like this

```
select rnum,sal
  from  
( select sal, rownum rnum

    from salary 
   order by sal desc ) 
 where rnum = 3;
```

`rownum` is not assigned until after the predicate phase so `rownum = 3` will always be false. Use a CTE or derived table then you can access the `rownum` from outside it.

Comment: select rownum,sal
  from  
( select sal 
    from salary 
   order by sal desc ) 
 where rownum = 3;
This thing i have already tried .... but answer is "data not found"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER FROM   (SELECT ROWNUM AS ROW_NUMBER, S.* FROM SALARY S)   WHERE ROW_NUMBER = 3;
```

This is incorrect. This will always return '3', because you are selecting ROW_NUMBER.

It should instead be "select *", as mentioned below:

```
select * from (select rownum as row_number, s.* from salary s) where row_number = 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

Is rownum an actual column in your salary table? If not, depending on your DB type, rownum is likely not supported.

Comment: select rownum from salary rownum<6 is working ....rownum is not attribute of my table it is a keyword ,i want to retrieve third row

Comment: data as follows 
a , 1000
b , 2000
c , 3000
d ,4000
e , 5000
f , 6000
e , 7000

Comment: select *from salary  


C S
a 1000
b 2000
c 3000
d 4000
e 5000
f 6000
g 7000