# Oracle Query Subselect with order by

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, subquery

I am normally using MS SQL and am a total rookie with oracle.

I get an oracle driver problem when I use the `ORDER BY` statement in my subquery.

Example (my real statement is much more complex but I doubt it matters to my problem - I can post it if needed):

```
SELECT col1
     , col2
     , (SELECT colsub FROM subtbl WHERE idsub = tbl.id AND ROWNUM=1 ORDER BY coldate) col3
FROM tbl
```

If I do such a construct I get an odbc driver error: ORA-00907: Right bracket is missing (translated from german, so bracket might be other word :)).

If I remove the `ORDER BY coldate` everything works fine. I couldn't find any reason why, so what do I wrong?

Comment: Try these similar questions: [tagged with Oracle and greatest-n-per-group tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to write the ROWNUM and the ORDER BY this way since the ORDER BY is evaluated after the WHERE clause, meaning that it has no effect in this case. An example is given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721620/rownum-in-oracle).

This also gets a little more complicated because it is hard to join a sub-query back to the main query if it is nested too deeply.

The query below won't necessarily work because you can't join between tbl and subtbl in this way.

```
SELECT 
  col1,
  col2,
  (
    select colsub
    from  (
      SELECT colsub 
       FROM subtbl 
       WHERE idsub = tbl.id
       order by coldate
    )
    where rownum = 1
  ) as col3
FROM tbl
```

So you'll need to use some sort of analytic function as shown in the example below:

```
SELECT 
  col1,
  col2,
  (SELECT max(colsub) keep (dense_rank first order by coldate) as colsub
   FROM subtbl 
   WHERE idsub = tbl.id
   group by idsub
) col3
FROM tbl
```

The `FIRST` analytic function is more complicated than it needs to be but it will get the job done.

Another option would be to use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function which would also solve the problem.

```
SELECT 
  col1,
  col2,
  (select colsub
   from (
     SELECT 
       idsub, 
       row_number() over (partition by idsub order by coldate) as rown,
       colsub
   FROM subtbl a 
   ) a
   WHERE a.idsub = tbl.id
   and a.rown = 1
) col3
FROM tbl
```

Comment: The last option approach with ROW_NUMBER() will be it. Thanks.

Comment: btw: Do people sometimes call you Austin Powers regarding your name :)?

Comment: Yes. And the guy from the Halloween movies too since the character is Michael Myers. Thankfully both are getting less frequent as time goes on.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is clear. You are using an order by in a sub-query. It does not make any sense using an order by in a sub-query so why would you want to do that?
Also you are using an order by on a sub-query that always returns 1 row. That also does not make any sense.

If you want the query result to be sorted use an order by at the highest level.

Comment: Why doesn't it make any sense? I get possible x rows from that sub select and make sure that I get only 1 row and the newest one. Works pretty fine in ms sql (and mysql) this way, so I guessed the world nr.1 database can handle this as well (just different syntax) :)

Comment: I found my mistake I guess. Have to JOIN the subselect because I need to order columns which aren't in my selection. A column sub query like this can only select one column in mssql, so prolly in oracle, too!?

Comment: @ypercube sub select may only result in 1 row at all, but the select can possible result more then 1 record, so I wanted just 1 and in this case the latest one.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. The comment was about what *"the world nr.1 database can handle"*

Comment: @ypercube Was kidding, a friend of me working for oracle and always tell me that they are nr.1 database... :)

Comment: @Rene: There are several examples of subqueries where one can use `ORDER BY` - but are useless in inline subqueries, like this one. The problem here is not the order by, but the `WHERE ROWNUM=1`.

Comment: A combination of where rownum<n and order by gives unexpected results in Oracle. This is because the records are first retrieved at random order and limited to the specified number. Only then the result is sorted. So you never know what records you get. Edit: Only now I read Mike's answer who also states this.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
select
  col1,
  col2,
  colsub
from(
  select
    col1   ,
    col2   ,
    coldate,
    max(coldate) over (partition by st.idsub) max_coldate
  from
    tbl    t,
    subtbl st
  where
    st.idsub = t.id)
where
  coldate = max_coldate
```