# Oracle: get X rows from point A

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I have a stored procedure which gets a list of items attached to a given configuration (each item is attached to one configuration ; if it's not (i.e. the field is `NULL`) then we consider it attaced to the default configuration (wich has its field `ISDEFAULT` to `1`). I would like to get the items using pagination. I remembered that the `ROWNUM` field starts at one, so I wrote (using 0 for the first page, and ten items per page):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  ITEMS item
WHERE
  (ROWNUM - 1) >= 0 and
  (ROWNUM - 1) < (0 + 10) and
  (item.CONFIGID = 0 or 
  item.CONFIGID is null and exists (SELECT config.CONFIGID FROM CONFIGURATION config WHERE config.CONFIGID = 0 and config.ISDEFAULT = 1));
```

This request returned me zero results.

I changed it to:

```
SELECT item.NAME,
item.ITEMID,
item.CONFIGID,
ROWNUM
FROM 
  ITEMS item
WHERE
      (ROWNUM - 1) >= 0 and
      (ROWNUM - 1) < (0 + 10) and
  (item.CONFIGID = 0 or 
  item.CONFIGID is null and exists (SELECT config.CONFIGID FROM CONFIGURATION config WHERE config.CONFIGID = 0 and config.ISDEFAULT = 1));
```

And it worked! Adding the `ROWNUM` in the `SELECT` statement fixed the issue.

Then I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  ITEMS item
WHERE
  ROWNUM >= (0 + 1) and
  ROWNUM < (0 + 1 + 10) and
  (item.CONFIGID = 0 or 
  item.CONFIGID is null and exists (SELECT config.CONFIGID FROM CONFIGURATION config WHERE config.CONFIGID = 0 and config.ISDEFAULT = 1));
```

I wrote back the `SELECT *` statement and moved the `- 1` to the other sides of the comparison operators (therefore they became `+ 1`). This works as well.

Can someone explain why my first query does not work and yields zero results whereas the other two work like a charm?

Comment: ROWNUM works in a special way. See this [question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721620/rownum-in-oracle

Comment: Thank you for the link but this does not explain why adding `ROWNUM` in the select statement fixes the issue.

Comment: ROWNUM is assigned after the WHERE clause is evaluated. You should be doing "TOP X" select in another way, like the link explains.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with ROWNUM.
Can you try to execute:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ITEMS item
 WHERE
  (ROWNUM - 1) >= 0 and
  (ROWNUM - 1) < (0 + 10);


SELECT item.NAME,
       item.ITEMID,
       item.CONFIGID,
       ROWNUM
  FROM ITEMS item
 WHERE
  (ROWNUM - 1) >= 0 and
  (ROWNUM - 1) < (0 + 10);
```

Both should work ok. Which means you have problem with second part of the filter.
The following subquery

```
(SELECT config.CONFIGID FROM CONFIGURATION config WHERE config.CONFIGID = 0 and config.ISDEFAULT = 1));
```

is uncorreleated. So it whould always return same result for any record. I think you have to add brackets into condition by item.CONFIGID:

```
(item.CONFIGID = 0) or 
(
item.CONFIGID is null and
exists (SELECT ...)
)
```

or

```
(item.CONFIGID = 0 or     
item.CONFIGID is null) and
exists (SELECT ...)
```

I think that is your problem. But not sure without seeing data.

Comment: The first request returns zero results, the second one returns ten results.

Comment: Which Oracle version? Any VPD policies on this table?

Comment: It's Oracle 10g and there are no VPD policy that I am aware of, it's just a regular table.