# How to skip/offset rows in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a very simple query for an Oracle DB (version 9).

Somehow I can get first 5 rows:

`select * from cities where rownum <= 5`

But skipping 5 rows returns an empty result:

`select * from cities where rownum >= 5`

Using:

- Oracle SQL Developer
- Oracle DB version 9

Why is the second query returning an empty result?

Comment: Have you tried searching? There are dozens of similar questions in SO.

Comment: Couldn't find any so far. Please let me know if you find the answer. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select rownum from salary where rownum=3;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457370/select-rownum-from-salary-where-rownum-3)

Comment: Newer Oracle versions support ANSI SQL's `FETCH FIRST`, but I don't know from which version... Try adding `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY` at the end. Combine with `ORDER BY`!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for pagination in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738181/best-practice-for-pagination-in-oracle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query to skip the first not n of rows.

```
select * from (
 select rslts.*, rownum as rec_no from (
  <<Query with proper order by (If you don't have proper order by you will see weird results)>>
 ) rslts
) where  rec_no > <<startRowNum - n>>
```

The above query is similar to pagination query below.

```
select * from (
 select rslts.*, rownum as rec_no from (
  <<Query with proper order by (If you don't have proper order by you will see weird results)>>
 ) rslts where  rownum <= <<endRowNum>>
) where  rec_no > <<startRowNum>>
```

Your cities query:

```
select * from (
 select rslts.*, rownum as rec_no from (
  select * from cities order by 1
 ) rslts
) where  rec_no > 5 <<startRowNum>>
```

Note: Assume first column in cities table is unique key

Answer (score 13):

In Oracle Database 12c (release 1) and above, you can  do this very simple, for skip 5 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM T OFFSET 5 ROWS
```

and for skip 5 rows and take 15 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM T OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 4):

Oracle increments `rownum` each time it adds a row to the result set.  So saying `rownum < 5` is fine; as it adds each of the first 5 rows it increments `rownum`, but then once `ruwnum = 5` the `WHERE` clause stops matching, no more rows are added to the result, and though you don't notice this `rownum` stops incrementing.

But if you say `WHERE rownum > 5` then right off the bat, the `WHERE` clause doesn't match; and since, say, the first row isn't added to the result set, `rownum` isn't incremented... so `rownum` can never reach a value greater than 5 and the `WHERE` clause can never match.

To get the result you want, you can use `row_number() over()` in a subquery, like

```
select *
  from (select row_number() over() rn, -- other values
          from table
         where -- ...)
 where rn > 5
```

**Update** - As noted by others, this kind of query only makes sense if you can 
control the order of the row numbering, so you should really use `row_number() over(order by`*something*`)` where *something* is a useful ordering key in deciding which records are "the first 5 records".

Comment: To apply ordering, use `over(order by MyColumn)`

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Do you know why this query doesn't work `select * from (select row_number() over (order by id) rn, c.* from cities c ) where rn > 3` ?
Error: `%s: invalid identifier`

Comment: @AntonIva: "doesn't work" as in "is invalid SQL"? Or "aborts execution with an error"? Or "returns different result than I expected" (if so what did you expect)?

Comment: Error as this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdpodlfbu9l7q8m/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2009.47.44.png?dl=0
What type of error is this? @Codo

Comment: In the screenshot, it appears you left off the `rn` in `row_number() over(order by id) rn`

Answer (score 1):

rownum is being increased only when a row is being output, so this type of condition won't work.
In any case, you are not ordering your rows, so what's the point?

Comment: This is a part of POC that I am working. The final version will be full SQL query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Used `row_number() over (order by id)`:

```
select * from
(select row_number() over (order by id) rn, c.* from countries c)
where rn > 5
```

Used `ROWNUM`:

```
select * from
(select rownum rn, c.* from countries c)
where rn > 5
```

**Important note:**

Using alias as `countries c` instead of `countries` is required! Without, it gives an error `"missing expression"`

Comment: The first query doesn't work because it doesn't name the `row_number() over(...)` expression to `rn` so `rn` is undefined.  Because `row_number() over()` is standard whereas `rownum` is Oracle-specific, I recommend using the former.

Comment: Sorry, yes I missed. Thanks, @Mark. Fixed. But it still gives an error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1uetavxft8l0jl/Screenshot%202016-12-06%2011.01.31.png?dl=0

Comment: Does the table have an `ID` column?  That's the identifier it's complaining about...

Comment: Thank you very much, @MarkAdelsberger. Yes, you are right. Fixed the answer too.

Comment: You can always type out the name of the table/view rather than using an alias. So for your example above, just type out 'countries', as in: SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM rn, countries.*
          FROM countries)
 WHERE rn > 5

Answer (score 1):

Even better would be:

```
select * from mytab sample(5) fetch next 1 rows only;
```

Sample clause indicates the probability of each row getting picked up in the sampling process. FETCH NEXT clause indicates the number of rows you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you can query your table with *skip* and *take*.

```
select * from (
 select a.*, rownum rnum from (
  select * from cities
 ) a
) WHERE rnum >= :skip + 1 AND rnum <= :skip + :take
```

This code works with Oracle 11g. With Oracle 12, there is already a better way to perform this queries with *offset* and *fetch*